# use while loops to calculate the sum of the odd number 1-25, and even number 1-50

Tags: java

i have problems with this program that i have to write. (First of all, english isnt my first language, therefore i have a hard time to understand what exactly i have to do for this program.)

---

```
Create an application Loops.java. The program must do the following:

Use a while loop to calculate the sum of the odd numbers 1-25.

Use a while loop to calculate the sum of the even numbers 1-50.
```

we are not adding odd number like `1+3+5+7+....+25,`
we also not adding odd number up until the total value is `25`.

the total value will be the sum of odd number ranging from `1 to 25`, as for even number will be from `1-50`

---

as for the requirement, there will be many probability,
such as `(1 + 3 = 5), (1 + 5 = 7), (1 +7 = 9)` and so on

I wonder, since odd number from `1 to 25` has total `13` odd numbers and even number from `1-50` has `25` even numbers, what is the limit of the while loops there is no limit for the total odd number.

Can anyone come up with this example?

Here is what i write at first, but after my professor explain the restriction and what i shouldn't do, I'm totally lost.

```
public class Loops
{   
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        int oddNumber = 1;
        int evenNumber = 2;

        while ( oddNumber < 25 )
        {
            oddNumber = oddNumber + 2;      
        }       
        System.out.printf ( "Total sum of the odd number is %d\n", oddNumber );

        while (evenNumber < 50)
        {
            evenNumber = evenNumber + 2;
        }
      System.out.printf ( "Total sum of the even number is %d\n", evenNumber );
    }
}
```

Comment: To prevent confusion. You are not calculating a sum, you are searching for all possible combinations of a set of numbers (odds and evens) to form a given (maximum?) sum. (Is there a mathematical term?)

Comment: i think u want to find all combinations of odd numbers such that their sum is between 1-25 and similar will be the case with even numbers. So is the possible combinations size is restricted to 2 only like you have said (1,3) or it can grow beyond that?

Comment: That is the thing that i dont understand, my professor said we need to calculate the sum of odd number ranging from 1-25 and even number ranging from 1-50. he gives us the range of even and odd number so that we know when to stop. the problem is, from 1 to 50, there are 25 even number, including 50. if the total value is not beyond 50, then i can see the end of the loop, which is very close. But the total value isnt 50, so i can add whatever even number i want ranging from 1-50. so i can addd 2+4+6+8+10+12...+50 or 4+8+12+16+...+50 and so on. I hope you understand what i am trying to say here.

Comment: Felk and Himansu, my professor said the control variable of the while loop will be either the odd number or the even number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Loops
{   
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        int oddNumber = 1;
        int totalOdd = 0;
        int evenNumber = 2;
        int totalEven = 0;

        while ( oddNumber <= 25 )
        {
            totalOdd = totalOdd + oddNumber;
            oddNumber = oddNumber + 2;      
        }       
        System.out.printf ( "Total sum of the odd number is %d\n", totalOdd);

        while (evenNumber <= 50)
        {
            totalEven = totalEven + evenNumber;
            evenNumber = evenNumber + 2;
        }
      System.out.printf ( "Total sum of the even number is %d\n", totalEven);
    }
}
```

Quick question, it says 1-25 and 1-50, does that include 25 and 50, or exclude 25 and 50???

If it's excluding, code is fine as is, else, change the < into <= for the 2 while loops. Your question was difficult to understand so let me know if this is what you were looking for! I added the 2 new variables, totalOdd and totalEven to capture the totals of the odds and evens. Before, you were just returning the value of the odd and even number at top, namely, 25 and 50. And the way you got there didn't make sense either, you were just adding by 2 on the odd and even trail until you got to the desired number that would stop the while loop. You weren't even tracking the number of iterations. So I changed the code to just add up every number from 1- 25 that's odd and every number 1-50 that's even, and displayed the results. If anything don't make sense, just ask.

---EDIT---

You said 25 and 50 ARE included, in which case, I have now updated the while loops to include the end numbers.

Comment: 25 and 50 is included... so you also think the question is hard to understand. Thank you, i thought am the only one that dont understand english. I feel like an idiot when i keep asking question on how to approach the problem and yet i dont understand how to do it because i just dont see the solution for this problem.

Comment: Not a problem, now I have updated the code to reflect this, please check and see if this is how it should be.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it and see if this is the format that my professor wants. i think will have to wait until tomorrow to find out. he's probably go to sleep already

Comment: That is how my professor want us to do. Thank you so much for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
public class Loops
{   
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        int oddNumber = 0;
        int evenNumber = 0;
        int number=1;
        while ( number < 50 )
        {
            if(number <= 25 && number%2!=0){
                 oddNumber=oddNumber+number;
             }else if(number%2==0){
                 evenNumber=evenNumber+number;
             }
            number++;
        }       

      System.out.printf ( "Total sum of the odd number is %d\n", oddNumber );


      System.out.printf ( "Total sum of the even number is %d\n", evenNumber );
    }
}
```

You simply need a single loop and manage summation of `odd` and `even` numbers logically.

Comment: indeed you deserve +1 for not showing any comment or explanation :)